# azure blob 400 and 404 http error on some requests

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-monitoring

As given in the graph. Not all, but a selected number of requests fails to make Azure blob put and Get. This number has gone significantly high at times.
Get has 404 and put has 400 http errors.

There are other question on [404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017960/azure-blob-storage-returns-404-on-put) and [400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805403/azure-blob-storage-400-bad-request) for Azure blobs but not sure if they represent this scenario.
How to track and solve this?

[image]

Comment: How do you do the operations put / get? Does it successfully put / get?

Comment: wow that's a lot of requests. what service plan are you on?